# PHP base path '/' not working for file system functions

Tags: php

I'm at a loss as to why I'm having this problem.  I'm running IIS on Windows 7 for development but have a Linux server for web hosting.

The problem is whenever I use a PHP system function, like `file_exists()` or `move_uploaded_file()`, using a path like `/support/images/flags/countries/` always fails.  The support directory is under the root directory of the site.  All the documentation I have read seems to state that the path should work.  Is this because I use Windows? Even the posts on SO seem to say it should work.

In order to get it to work correctly I have to use a path like `{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/support/images/flags/countries`

Can anyone explain why my thinking is wrong?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you should use the other bar. `\ `

Comment: @PhiterFernandes: According to IIS documentation either '\'  or  '/' is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not a good idea, especially if you're planning to use CLI in your application, where server variables are not available. You should try something like

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

in your script instead, or consider introducing a custom constant which would contain the full system path to your root folder - e.g,

```
define('MY_APP_ROOT', '/my/full/path/');
```

Much easier than relying on Apache or IIS in this.

Comment: And then there is still the issue of `/support/images/flags/countries` according to example, it is used inside the script and not displayed to the user as a URI.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov:  At this point my application has no plans on using CLI but your answer is something to think about.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Also think about having a separate constant for your data folder as well, if you keep it outside the www-root.

Comment: Seems no one else is going to answer my question.  I will accept your answer only because of the information you provided about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.  I will incorporate your advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant in PHP. Files and folders work somewhat different in Linux. Using this will retain compatibility in Windows and Linux.

Here is a small function I've been using to build paths:

```
function buildPath(...$segments){
    return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $segments);
}

echo buildPath('path', 'to', 'folder');
```

Also another compatibility know-how is that Linux is case sensitive, also in databases when selecting a "TabLe". In Windows it will work no-matter how you write it, on Linux it must be exactly the same.

Creating a link in the browser using forward slashes is the way to go, like for example linking people to `/var/wwww/css/index.css` (most likely just `./css/index.css`) but for internal operations a backslash is required in Linux.

Comment: Forward and backward slashes are usually acceptable both by IIS and Apache, so I don't think this is what brings OP the trouble.

Comment: @Xorifelse:  I always use lower case so that's not the problem.  UNIX type OS's always use the '/' directory separator.  But thanks for your answer, I will ponder for awhile.

Comment: Just saying, the starting sign of '\' relative to root and `/` relative to file. Personally I don't use a complex directory structure and I normally include files or read files in the script relative to it by using  `../`to go back a directory.

Comment: @Xorifelse:  In my HTML files I always use the '/xxx/yyy/zzz/file.php' directory structure.  Even the PHP header() command accepts this format.  This is to avoid possible problems if I ever change the location of any HTML files.